# Unable to get values from NSDictionary is ios

Tags: ios, nsdictionary

My NSDictionary output with NSLog shows:

```
{
    "filename" : "mytest100.txt",
    "filedesc" : "File Description here",
    "data" : [

    ]
 }
```

But when I do: `NSString *filename = [dict objectForKey:@"filename"];` it crashes on this line.

What am I doing wrong? This seems trivial.

Comment: What is the error message you get when it crashes?

Comment: Your dictionary is called dict? No uppercase or misspellings?

Comment: Correct, no misspelling. The error message is: [__NSCFString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0Xec95e10. If it's referring to "filename", it certainly is there, it's not making much sense.

Comment: Sounds like `dict` is a string rather than a dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error message you're getting, the `dict` variable does not hold an `NSDictionary`, but rather and `NSString`.

Track back up your code looking for where you assign the `dict` variable and you'll surely see it's being set to something that's not a dictionary.

Comment: well, it could be, but I suspect not. Here's the proceeding code:

for(NSDictionary dict in array){
    NSLog("DICTIONARY IS: %@", dict);
    NSString *filename = [dict objectForKey:@"filename"];
}

array comes from:

NSArray *array = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:myfilename];

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite, if you disagree, then run this command `NSLog(@"class -> %@", [dict class]);` right before you perform `objectForKey`

Comment: I don't disagree, I"m just trying to find out what my error is :)

output is: class -> __NSCFtring

So, you guys are right. Can you tell me how to turn that string into a valid NSDictionary? Thanks again. Right on the money with your answers.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite, the string you posted in your OP looks like JSON. If what you're storing to disc is JSON, then you'll need to deserialize it. I've had a lot of luck with SBJson, but there are others.

Comment: That is correct, I am storing a JSON string in a file and reading it back and try to parse it. The issue is that I don't know much Objective C, I just started out and my JSON is actually more complex than what I showed here, it has nested array of other objects, so I'm not sure how to parse the JSON back into a complex object which has simple properties as well as arrays with complex objects. I just started out with a few simple properties and got stuck here. I was hoping to get a NSDictionary from the JSON and then read each property as a NSString or NSArray.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
NSDictionary *d = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"foo" forKey:@"bar"];
NSLog(@"%@", d);
```

output is:

```
{
    bar = foo;
}
```

Notice that there are no quotes logged in the key or value?  Unless your key and value is of the form @"\"foo\"", my guess is that you don't really have a dictionary there.

I'd put my money on a string representing JSON.  The crash is because objectForKey: is an unrecognized selector on a string.